# How to Find Zip codes by Zip and Distance

Tags: php, mysql

Please, help me. 
I need to find all zip codes by zip and distance by miles.
I know a few ways, how to.
I can create table location, zip_code, lat, lng
and use mySql for find all but it can takes too many time because,

1 - Find lat, lng by location.zip_code = xxxx

2 - Find by mySql -

```
SELECT 
`id`, 
`zip_code`, 
( 6373 * acos( cos( radians( :lat ) ) * cos( radians( `lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `long` ) - radians( :long ) ) + sin(radians(:lat)) * sin(radians(`lat`)) ) ) `distance` 
FROM `location` 
HAVING `distance` < :distance 
ORDER BY `distance` LIMIT 25
```

Return **$zip_codes**
3 - find by sql

```
Select * From **** Where zip IN ($zip_codes)
```

Maybe you know how to optimize this case?

Comment: break your question into pieces; do you have a static database of zip codes? do you use another website plugin/api ? can you show the structure of your MySQL data?